# Is it possible to publish session form PHP and mobile connect stream?

Tags: php, ios, mobile, tokbox

I am using [TOKBOX](https://tokbox.com/). I want to publish audio and video from PHP side. and only subscribe in iOS(Swift). is it possible? if yes, Please describe more. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "publish" or "subscribe" your videos/audio. Do you mean stream them from PHP servers?

Comment: Yes, "Publish"  audio/video from PHP server and subscribe from iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

OpenTok QA staff here.

Unfortunately, you cannot publish directly from PHP. You can generate sessions and tokens, and use those values from a Javascript client to publish. See the developer guides here:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/

Regarding subscribers, you can subscribe from many different types of clients, including iOS Swift. You can find tutorials, APIs, samples, etc., here:

https://tokbox.com/developer/samples/

https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/tree/master/Basic-Video-Chat

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was found it's. its possible I was try in both languages Objective-C and Swift. its working fine in Objective-C but same code not working in Swift. here is link what I was try. https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/subscribe-stream/ios/ I don't know its issue in **TOKBOK** or not.